# How to upload multiple files with Robot Framework

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I am currently doing automation testing with an app on a browser using Robot Framework. Uploading 1 file at a time is easy using Choose File keyword. But how do you upload multiple files? In my case, I need to select all the files in that directory and upload them.

Answer (score 2):

For me this Python custom keyword did the job with file paths separated with `\n` (it at least proved to work in Chrome):

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class CustomKeywords:
  def choose_files(self, locator, file_paths):
    sl = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    sl.find_element(locator).send_keys(file_paths)
```

The keyword can then be used like:
`Choose Files | my_upload_field_locator | ${CURDIR}/file_1.csv \n ${CURDIR}/file_2.csv`

With some additional Python this could be improved to not require `\n` for the file paths.